# Por que o CORS não bloqueia Postman e derivados?

Tags: api, restful, cors

Estou criando uma API RESTful com NodeJS e express e nela, estou utilizando o cors para "controle" de requisições.

No navegador funciona, se eu faço uma requisição a essa API pelo console do site aqui do StackOverflow, eu não consigo usar, ele está bloqueado, se eu for em meu domínio no qual eu liberei acesso desta forma:

```
app.get('/product/:id', cors({ origin: "https://www.meusite.com.br" })
```

Eu consigo êxito ao usar a API.

Porém, a dúvida é, se eu for de qualquer lugar utilizando o Postman, o Insomnia ou derivados, eu consigo usufruir de qualquer recurso da API.

Por que isso acorre?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Porque o CORS é uma implementação de segurança nos motores dos navegadores, e como tal valida as requisições *cross-domain*.

Já outras ferramentas como  o **POSTMAN** não estão executando no contexto do navegador, e portanto, se não implementarem o CORS, podem executar qualquer *request* sem problema.

Se houver alguma restrição do lado server que faça alguma validação, o *request* pode falhar o *response*, mas a requisição funciona bem, afinal são aplicações que não estão restringindo as requisições

Comment: Entendi... Existe algo semelhante ao "cors" para qualquer requisição de qualquer lugar? Ou teria que validar isso manualmente?

Comment: está dizendo a validação server? se for esse link ajuda muito: https://enable-cors.org/server.html